# Facebook Javascript SDK: if page(that user is admin of) category name === "Musician/Band" on login check

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using Graph API.
I want to log user if page that he is admin of, matches category name === "Musician/Band".
i tried asking for

> manage_pages

```
<fb:login-button 
    scope="public_profile,email,**manage_pages**"
    onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

but that gave me a bunch of stuff that i do not need.
So my question is...is there a way to get that category name and compare it when user clicks login button and allowes right permissions?

Comment: you get the pages with /me/accounts, and you can check out the api reference to know which fields you can get for each page. this is quite broad, please add your api call too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but that gave me a bunch of stuff that i do not need.

If by that you mean asking for `manage_pages` permission is too intrusive, you can ask for [`pages_show_list`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-pages_show_list) instead. That will give you access to the list of pages the user is an admin of, without giving your app further capabilities to perform administrative tasks on those pages.

Then you can make a request such as `me/accounts?fields=category_list` to get the categories of the pages the user is admin of. You will still have to go through that list and look for the category you are interested in - there is no filtering for something like this.

And it will not prevent users from logging in to your app in the first place; you can only decide how you treat them based on whether they admin such a page or not afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's something I did not understand and I did not get from the documentation. Yes, I did not want to scare the user with the search for unnecessary permissions, so i needed something little less intrusive, like this solution. :)